Does polars for Rust support NewType datatypes?
I am looking to use the polars crate for Rust but with custom datatypes that are effectively transparent new-type wrappers around supported primitives.
Here is a simple example of what I'm trying to achieve, but doesn't work (rustc-stable v1.79.0, polars v0.41.3):
use polars::prelude::*;

#[repr(transparent)]
struct NewType(f64);

fn main() {
    
    let value1 = NewType(4.77);
    let value2 = NewType(-6.1);
    
    // doesn't work because `NewType` is unknown by Polars.
    let ser = Series::new("a", &[value1, value2]);
    println!("{ser}");
}

The compiler error is trait polars::prelude::NamedFrom<&[NewType; 2], _> is not implemented for polars::prelude::Series.
This makes sense, but I can't implement NamedFrom for Series because of Rust's orphan rules.
Are there any other options for using new-type datatypes in polars-rust?

It looks like you can implement PolarsObject and then use a ObjectChunked<NewType> instead of Series.

You can just convert the slice.
